# How to set some sections in word not to print?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm composing some of my notes in Word, while I put many details inside, when printing, I'd like to only print some important sections.

Is it possible to set some sections in word "not printable"?

I'm using Microsoft Word 2007 on Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to compose your notes in this way :
- edit them in the "display all" mode (¶ pressed) ;
- mark certains sections of text as hidden ;

When you will print the note, by default, hidden text won't print.